# JQGrid row selection

Tags: jqgrid

Hi 
When i try to use JQGrid and load values from server (JSON load) , everything seems to work fine except that any row i click ,only the first rwo is selected. Any pointers as to where i could be going wrong?

Thanks
Sunil

Answer (score 2):

Typically the problem exist if the JSON data has **duplicate** in the `ids`. For example if you place the same id in every row posted from the server you will have exactly the same behavior which you describe.

Comment: i found the issue . I had to include key:true  in the right field in the column model...

Comment: @Sunil: I suppose it is not only problem which you has. It is better if you include the jqGrid definition and the JSON data returned from the server. You can just modify your question and include all the information.

Comment: thanks Oleg .An additon to this is that my server side sorting is not working properly. I dont even get the hand icons on top of my columns . I had the grid property sortable: true,.I even add this sortable: true, to all the columns.Still i dont get that hand pointer to sort columns.(unable to post the entire grid code here.)